# state_pressed=true is hilighting on clicking anywhere

Tags: android, selector

I used `selector` to change background of a `LinearLayout` when it is pressed.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/holo_blue" ></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"></item>
</selector>
```

But whenever I click anywhere on screen, background of my LinearLayout changes. Any idea why such unexpected behavior?

Comment: This sounds like the expected behavior? Do you mean that even when you click on non-clickable child views, such as a TextView, that the LinearLayout still changes background?

Comment: you got it right.. it is changing color even if I click outside of the bounds of 'clickable' LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your child views are not consuming any touch events, but the `LinearLayout` has expressed interest in touch events by using a background with a pressed state (this is my intuition based on experience; I am not sure whether this is explicitly stated in the Android documentation). One way to resolve this would be to make the `TextView`s clickable using the xml attribute `clickable="true"` without assigning any click behavior in code, but this obviously doesn't scale particularly well if you have a large number of child views. Hopefully that provides a good starting point though.